# Android quickaction for 1.6

Tags: android

Is there any possibility to do the quickactionbar like in 2.3  for 1.6 .please help me on this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you look around at all? http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/wiki/HowThisWorks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good guide here:

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

and at a glance through the source it's based on here:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-quickactions/

it looks as though it should work with 1.6